# Hamburger menu styled differently

Tags: codenameone, hamburger-menu

I have a strange problem I need some help with.

Very recently I started experiencing a problem with the hamburger/side menu.

On startup our production version renders the hamburger menu in black but the current dev version renders in blue.

Once I login on the dev version, and start using the app, when I go into one of our application's forms, the hamburger menu disappears. The side menu can be activated by a slide-in motion.

I first started seeing this when doing a cloud/device build, not on the simulator.

A day or so after I got this on the simulator.

Thinking it may have been an environment issue (specifically I had been doing some theming with the GUI designer), I set everything up on my Windows VM, with a clean copy of the production code copied out of SVN - but I get this problem on the 'clean' version.

As I inherited this code, I was able to go back to the machine left by the previous developer and in running their version in the simulator all was fine. Black hamburger on login screen and present on our application forms.

I submitted the code to do a SAAS device build but then a library update ran on this previous developers machine, and I now get blue Hamburger at startup and missing on our application forms in the simulator - the same problem that I got.

Seems to point to something in the new libs. So, I then pegged the versioned build back a level (3.6 rather than latest) - to try to resolve any 'new version' issues but I get the same problem.

I guess we are missing some initialisation steps out on the new sidemenu - our code has been in place for a few years now, so ideally I would like to build against the previous version of the CN1 libs where we didn't have this problem until I have time to work what we are missing.

I thought versioned build would give me this ability but the problem persists- any assistance would be gratefully accepted.

UBUNTU 16.04

Windows 8&10

Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We transitioned to the on-top menu over the weekend. This has been [announced a while back](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-on-top-menu.html) and despite that as usual people were caught a bit off guard. We posted multiple updates on that to the [blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/) so you should probably keep an eye on that.

The on-top side menu uses the default `TitleCommand` UIID styling where the old side menu had a different UIID but I'm guessing the engineer in charge used the theme constant `sideMenuImage` which we didn't include in the first release of on top side menu. This should be fixed in the update coming out this Friday (November 3rd 2017).

FYI You can disable the on-top mode using `Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false)` although I would recommend sticking with it as it's WAY better.

Comment: Much appreciated, and grateful for such a quick response - I'll read the linked article and make sure we are doing the right things!